# Error with Send To Function

Tags: wss-3.0, send-to-destination

I'm running into an error when attempting to do a Send To between 2 libraries in SP2007 (WSS). (Yes, I know it's old. :)

Some things to note:

- I am using the correct "http://servername/sitename/libraryname" syntax for the Send To.
- The resulting URL would ber below 128 characters.
- Both libraries are in the same site collection (in fact, they're on the same site).
- I am a Site Admin with Full Control permissions on both libraries and elsewhere on the site.

I am able to Send To from Library 2 to Library 1 without any issues, but when I try to send from Library 1 to Library 2, I run into problems and see the "Copying to destination did not complete successfully" message.

Any guesses as to what might be the cause of this? Why can I Send To one way, but not the other?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the same versioning configuration in both lists.